# Put a link to a tutorial on the Tex in the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, faq-proposed

I have no idea how to use either of the Tex methods supported here.

How about putting a link to the instructions or a tutorial on both in the FAQ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The advice from the [question/answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-should-go-in-the-math-stackexchange-faq/117#117) in the proposed faq:

---

Q: **How do I type math in my question/answer/comment?**

A: For simple formulae, you can use `<sup></sup>` to write superscripts and `<sub></sub>` for subscripts:
`y<sub>1</sub>=x<sup>2</sup>+3`becomes y<sub>1</sub>=x<sup>2</sup>+3

For more complicated formulae, you can use [TeX markup](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ctan.org%2Ftex-archive%2Finfo%2Flshort%2Fenglish%2Flshort.pdf&ei=uW9fTK7sKIK88gb8wqm1DQ&usg=AFQjCNGlIFiqkZqWlimc_td_2FA38ZkhMQ&sig2=0pjXu1uSjJiPeH-cdV1Yug).
To type inline TeX equations, surround the code with `$`'s, e.g.

> `$c = \sqrt{ a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos \theta }` ⇒ $c = \sqrt{ a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos \theta }$

To put the equation in its own line, surround with `$$`'s, e.g.

> `$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt\pi}2$$` ⇒ $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt\pi}2$$

AMS math environment is also supported, e.g.

> ```
> \begin{align}
> >       \cos x &= \frac{\sin 2x}{2 \sin x} \\\\
> >     \sin^2 x &= \cos^2 x - \cos 2x
> >     \end{align}
> ```
>
> ⇒
>   \begin{align}
> >   \cos x &= \frac{\sin 2x}{2 \sin x} \\\\
> > \sin^2 x &= \cos^2 x - \cos 2x
> > \end{align}

Note that you need 4 backslashes for a new line. Many times you also need extra backslashes to avoid conflict with Markdown syntax, e.g.

> `$$\alpha^{-1}_{-1} + \beta_{-2}$$` won't work, as `_..._` is interpreted as *italics*.
>
> $$\alpha^{-1}_{-1} + \beta_{-2}$$
>
> Use `$$\alpha^{-1}\_{-1} + \beta\_{-2}$$` instead.
>
> $$\alpha^{-1}\_{-1} + \beta\_{-2}$$

If you are unfamiliar with TeX, you can find a question that uses the markup you'd like to use, then right click and select show source.

If you have detailed questions about TeX or LaTeX, **this is not the appropriate place to ask them**. Please use a dedicated TeX help site such as http://tex.stackexchange.com or http://www.latex-community.org/forum/

---

Feel free to edit or comment on the linked post if there is anything specific you'd like to see.

As for the official [math.stackexchange faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq), that can only be touched by a site admin, so it will take a while for the community proposed faq to propagate there.

Comment: I guess I'll give up on an admin noticing this. Thank you for the instructions.

Comment: @Lance: I've updated this answer to incorporate advice from other sources. I will also try to get into contact with an admin to get a link to the unofficial faq inserted.

Comment: Relevant: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The first TexMarkup link is obsolete. It redirects to the following http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf Can you please update it?