# How to Write Math Equation Here

Tags: discussion, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do we have an equation editing HOWTO?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto)

I think my questions and answers always need editing from proffesionals. I am ashamed of my self.

How do everyone else can write beautifully. Things like x^2 or (A+B)/C. How do you do that?

Can we do that in HTML?

Can I feature questions and answers here on my site.

Comment: I should point out that this question has already been asked before (e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/934/where-is-the-latex-reference-please), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1078/264), and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1017/264)), and it is also dealt with in [this supplemental FAQ post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/117/264), and so we should close it as a duplicate.

Comment: I think the reason so many people ask is because it is not in the slightest way clear how to do so. Not once does it say in the 'tutorial' when you signup how.

Comment: I agree strongly with Ben Hughes. But I think the real reason is this: Mathematics Stack Exchange is primarily intended for experienced mathematicians interacting with each other, not for beginners or amateurs (of which I am one). So it is expected that the experienced mathematicians already know how to format mathematical equations in LaTeX, TeX, etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No need to be ashamed - it unfortunately is not clearly indicated where to see how to format math expressions on the site.

You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/464/264) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/161783).
 If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

If you see a piece of LaTeX you want to know the code for on the site, you can right click on it, go to "Show Math As", then choose "TeX Commands" - this is a good way of picking up how to do things (this [currently does not work with Chrome](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3904/264) unfortunately).