# How do I insert a table when asking a question?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, markdown

I'm having a hard time to insert a table here when I'm asking a question. Any help would be appreciated.
Also, is there any, not too expensive, math programs that allow me to enter math terms and equations kind of thing?

Thank you

Tom

Comment: Related on tables: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables

Comment: Have to tried www.wolframalpha.com ? :)

Comment: There is [an entry on tables](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/29979#29979) in the MathJax tutorial. Some support for tables is now available also in MarkDown, as illustrated [in this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question/32850#32850).

Answer (score 37):

Regarding how to write general math expressions on the site, [my answer here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3990/264) covers that well I think.

Specifically for tables, you can use [LaTeX's `\array` command](http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/Array_(LaTeX_environment)). The `tabular` command, which only works in text mode, is not available here, so if you want to include text in your table, you will have to do some tinkering. Here is an example table:

```
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{Column A} & \text{Column B} \\ \hline
\text{Row 1} & 5 & \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Row 2} & \int & 8 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
```

produces

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{Column A} & \text{Column B} \\ \hline
\text{Row 1} & 5 & \oplus \\ \hline
\text{Row 2} & \int & 8 \\\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: +1 Great example! I adapted it to display $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline&\zeta (3)&\zeta (2)\\ \hline\sigma&3+4\ln(1+4\sqrt{2})& 2+5\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\\ \hline\tau&-3+4\ln(1+\sqrt{2})&-2+5\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\\ \hline\mu=1+\dfrac{\sigma}{\tau}& \dfrac{8\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}{4\ln(1+\sqrt{2})-3}&\dfrac{10 \ln \left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}{5 \ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)-2}\\ \hline \end{array}$$

Comment: +1 Thanks. I had to try it out on one of my answers. Sorry about the bump.

Comment: Somehow, it doesn't work anymore...

Answer (score 8):

(This is a CW answer, everybody is welcome to extend or improve it.)

[Markdown support for tables](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) has been [enabled network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/196432), this offers an alternative to the MathJax/LaTeX `array` environment for simple tables. MathJax can be used inside the Markdown table entries.

#### A simple example

*Source:*

```
| Function | Addition theorem |
| -------- | ---------------- |
| **Sine** | $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x) \cos(y) + \cos(x) \sin(y)$ |
| **Cosine** | $\cos(x+y) = \cos(x) \cos(y) - \sin(x) \sin(y)$ |
```

*Result:*

| Function | Addition theorem |
| --- | --- |
| **Sine** | $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x) \cos(y) + \cos(x) \sin(y)$ |
| **Cosine** | $\cos(x+y) = \cos(x) \cos(y) - \sin(x) \sin(y)$ |

#### More examples:

*Source:*

```
| What | MathJax |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Matrix   | $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ |
| Equation with a tag | \begin{equation} x^2+y^2=z^2 \tag{1} \end{equation}  |
| Centered formula    | $$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$$ |
```

*Result:*

| What | MathJax |
| --- | --- |
| Matrix | $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ |
| Equation with a tag | \begin{equation} x^2+y^2=z^2 \tag{1} \end{equation} |
| Centered formula | $$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$$ |

#### Resources

- [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) on Meta Stack Exchange
- [Tables](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) in the Markdown help.
- [GitHub-flavored Markdown table syntax](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-)
- [Network-wide feature request to support MathJax in tables](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32841/network-wide-feature-request-to-support-mathjax-in-tables)

#### Notes

- There is currently  a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support/357525#357525) when MathJax is used in the Markdown table header.

Answer (score 7):

Since my example given in a comment to Zev Chonoles's answer and adapted from it, due to some reason, does not display properly now, I repeat it here.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline&\zeta (3)&\zeta (2)\\\hline\sigma&3+4\ln(1+4\sqrt{2})&2+5\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\\\hline\tau&-3+4\ln(1+\sqrt{2})&-2+5\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\\\hline\mu=1+\dfrac{\sigma}{\tau}&\dfrac{8\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}{4\ln(1+\sqrt{2})-3}&\dfrac{10\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}{5\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)-2}\\\hline\end{array}$$

It is produced by

`$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
    &\zeta (3)&\zeta (2)\\  \hline
\sigma&3+4\ln(1+4\sqrt{2})&2+5\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\\  
   \hline
\tau&-3+4\ln(1+\sqrt{2})&-2+5\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\\  \hline
\mu=1+\dfrac{\sigma}{\tau}&\dfrac{8\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}{4\ln(1  \sqrt{2})-3}& \dfrac{10\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}  {5\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)-2}\\ \hline
\end{array}$$`

Comment: Amusingly, without even first looking at your post, I noticed that your comment had broken and then proceeded to fix it, figuring that it's the same problem [I was having here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4385/264). Should I rebreak it?

Comment: That or perhaps better you could add a short comment explaining how you have fixed it.