# How do I import a table from excel in decent format?

Tags: support, mathjax

How do I import a table from excel in decent format ?
I want to ask a question at MSE and import a table into my question.
With decent I mean that it must look nice and not like a list or such.
Maybe this is a duplicate, if so Im sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by a "decent" format? Where do you want to import the table to?

Comment: I edited, maybe that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

For tables you can use array environment, see e.g. [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question) or [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5044#5044).

Getting a table into MathJax is not necessarily very different from getting table into LaTeX document, so you might have a look at [Comprehensive list of tools that simplify the generation of LaTeX tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414/9954) on TeX.SE.

A minimalist solution would be to save table from excel to tab-delimited text and then replace tabs by & and end of lines by \ (or \\hline, if you prefer). This can be done, for example, using [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) or some similar tool. Then you just add 
`\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}...\end{array}`
manually.

For example the following worked for me (I use Sed port for Windows):
`sed -f pom.sed input.txt > output.tex`
The file pom.sed contains

```
s/  /\&/g
s/$/\\\\\\hline/
```

(The space in first line is in fact a tab character.)

Of course, there are many different tools, I would use this because I am used to working with sed. (It is useful for many different things I often use.)