# Ways to make a table in a question?

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

I know there exist https://tex.stackexchange.com/ but I am looking for a way to draw a table in math.stackexchange box. So, my question is:

> Is there a way to make a table in the question box?

I found the code below in a question (I made some changes in it).

What kind of table can be produced here? (I mean with or without borders, shading, etc.)

Can you paste some tex code in answer, that would contain various table(s)?

$$ 
\begin{array}{c||c||c||c}
p & q & F(p,q)\\
\hline
\sin x +\cos x +\dfrac{t\tan x}{1+\cos x} & \top & \top& \frac13\\
\hline
\top & \sqrt 5 & \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x}{x-2}\\
\hline
\bot & \top &\top\\
\hline
\bot & \bot &\top\\
\end{array} 
$$

Comment: @Arthur :Thank you first ,but I want to ask a question with some table in math.stack . How can I use "\requires{package}" in math mod ? is it between dollar dollar  ? or ...

Comment: That's what "math mode" means here, yes: Between dollar signs.

Comment: See also: [How do I insert a table when asking a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4240)

Comment: The topic of arrays as tables comes up in various Answers under the MathJax Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference, but [this Answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5044/3111) is perhaps the most relevant.