# Feature Request: Support Latex Tables on math.stackexchange?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

#### [Math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) already supports quite a bit of $\LaTeX$ mark-up using `mathjax`. What do you think about supporting the $\LaTeX$ tables?

#### In Stack overflow mark-up language, a user could write something like the following:

```
$ % dollar sign begins LaTeX-style mark-up
\begin{table}
  \caption{Table Title}
  \begin{tabular}{ccl}
    % `ccl` option represents the following:
    % left   column centered
    % middle column centered 
    % right  column left-justified
    \toprule % print a horizontal line
    Column Header 1 & Col_H 2 & Col_H 3\\
    \midrule
    r1 c1 & r1 c2 & r1 c3 \\ % row 1
    r2 c1 & r2 c2 & r2 c3 \\ % row 2
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
$ % dollar sign ends LaTeX-style mark-up
```

#### The output would look like this:

[image: Rendering of Latex Table]

Comment: I'm curious what specific difficulty exists in making do with the `array` environment in $\LaTeX$ for this sort of thing?

Comment: I don't think that LaTeX tables outside of the math environment are supported by MathJax. I also think it would make a lot more sense for StackExchange to support [MarkDown Tables](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#tables) before implementing their own LaTeX tables. There's already plenty of software out there for MarkDown tables and it could be readily applied across the StackExchange network.

Comment: Is there a good reason for putting this entire question in **boldface**?

Comment: What Mark McClure requested would be nice. Don't know if there is technical reason why we don't have that. Anyway, with MathJax you can do this with an array. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4240/11619) for pointers/examples.

Comment: Some posts on Meta Stack Exchange related to Marc McClure's and Jyrki Lahtonen's comments (about Markdown and tables): 
[Is there Markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566), 
[Can we add Markdown support for tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138946) and
[Please add support for tables in answers and questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5255).