# Network-wide feature request to support MathJax in tables

Tags: discussion, mathjax, formatting, markdown, stackexchange

Many of us here frequently use MathJax, whether for this site or another site on the SE Network. Recently SE added support for tables, but ignored the needs of the communities with MathJax support, who wish to be able to type TeX symbols/formulas/etc. as well.

#### [This is the feature request on Meta.SE, to support MathJax in tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357525/391772).

Here's some network-wide examples where such support would be needed (please add anymore if you're aware of any!):

- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1257/5 (here MathJax is only needed for 3 symbols and the rest doesn't need MathJax at all, so it's the perfect example where Markup tables mixed with some MathJax expressions would be ideal).
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1720/5
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1247/5
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3857/5
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/361/5

Comment: By "TeX community" you probably do not mean [tex.se] - that site does not have MathJax enabled. When using MathJax, many people employ the array environment - see the answers here: [How do I insert a table when asking a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4240)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, the 4 examples I gave in my post do exactly what you suggest: they use the array environment to make tables. However it can be extremely tedious when all you need is to do is put one formula in a big table.

Comment: Good suggestion to put on the main meta, I guess they haven't enabled MathJax in tables yet as the main meta doesn't support it. In the meantime we can use [ChatJax](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) to get round it.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Those are both good points. Maybe MathJax does work, but we don't know, since MathJax doesn't work on main Meta? Also, I hadn't thought about ChatJax. Does it render the TeX in my main meta post, properly for you when you're using ChatJax? I can't see right now, largely because I'm not even sure if ChatJax works on an Android smartphone :)

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSMNt.png) showing what I see in your post after using robjohn's bookmarklet.

Comment: @MartinSleziak so it's good to know that it works with ChatJax! **When writing an answer, it should not be assumed though, that every single viewer will have ChatJax installed.**

Comment: @NikeDattani I am fully aware of that. I have simply responded to your question: "Does it render the TeX in my main meta post, properly for you when you're using ChatJax?" (I consider use of bookmarklet secondary to the main  question, since most users do not have it installed. But since you asked about it, I have added screenshot. I guess we have to wait until tables are enabled at least on some site with MathJax to see how it actually works.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks again!

Comment: I tried to remove mention of the TeX community which seemed inaccurate

Comment: @Calvin upon re-reading, I agree. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Yes, @NikeDattani The ChatJax bookmarklet works on Android devices. I've used it in The h  Bar (physics chat) on a Galaxy S9 phone, mostly with the Samsung browser (which uses the Blink engine). It also works on chatroom transcripts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So it seems that tables are now enabled here. Here is a CW-answer for testing how they work with MathJax.

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| Limit | $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ |
| Matrix | $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ |
| Cardinals | $\mathfrak c^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$ |

| More tests | Mathjax |
| --- | --- |
| Equation with a tag | \begin{equation} x^2+y^2=z^2 \tag{1} \end{equation} |
| Centered formula | $$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$$ |

Comment: There is a slight [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357525/391772) when MathJax is in the header though. It seems.